# Widget "FlatButton" was strikethrough in the center

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-widget

The Widget "FlatButton" was strikethrough in the center, please how do I correct it (To Remove the strikethrough)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[`FlatButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html) is deprecated, that's why you are seeing line trough. Use  [`TextButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html) instead.

```dart
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Image.asset(""),
),
```

Here is the note from [doc.](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons)

[image]